# PyPDF2 Merge/Append pages to end of document

Tags: python, append, pypdf

I can't figure out the function to get PyPDF2 to merge PDF files dropped into a watched folder to the END of a file rather than the beginning. I'm VERY new to python so I'm sure I'm missing something simple and greatly appreciate any help one of you incredible wizards can do to guide me.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import time
import os
import sys
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfMerger

class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "C:\\Users\\Grayden\\Desktop\\PDF_Trial"
    FILENAME = "invoices.pdf"

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            if event.src_path.endswith(".pdf"):
                print("New PDF file added: %s" % event.src_path)
                merge_pdfs(Watcher.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, Watcher.FILENAME)

def merge_pdfs(directory, output_filename):
    pdf_list = []
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
                filepath = os.path.join(foldername, filename)
                pdf_list.append(filepath)

    pdf_merger = PdfMerger()
    for pdf_path in pdf_list:
        with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
            pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_file, strict=False)
            pdf_merger.append(pdf_reader)

    with open(os.path.join(directory, output_filename), 'wb') as file:
        pdf_merger.write(file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

I assumed that using the merge function would simply add this new file to the end rather than defult to the start. The documentation refers to using the append function rather than merge, however I'm struggling to make sense of it due to my limited knowledge and most of my attempts simply throw errors so I went back to the merge function.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: I think I'm following you but as I mentioned I am like BRAND spanking new to this (like 2 weeks into coding with python) so I'm trying to just follow your logic. So apologies in advance if I've misinterpreted.

If I follow what you're saying I should have my script use the watchdog on the target folder. Then when the new pdf is added it should open the 'old pdf' file, append the 'new pdf' file then save and close.

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.